# Get generated content in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I would like to get the generated content (i.e. the whole HTML page generated by my CF scripts) in the onRequestEnd event in ColdFusion 10. Is there a function which will do this, I can't find one in the docs?

Thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot specifically test for ColdFusion 10 at the moment as I don't have a CF10 server in front of me, but this works on CF9:

```
allOfIt = getPageContext().getOut().getString();
```

I have no reason to think it would be different on CF10, but sorry that I cannot give a more definitive answer.

I'll be able to test in about 4h, and will update answer with my findings.

Comment: Confirming that this works in CF10. `moo
<cfscript>
 writeDump(getPageContext().getOut().getString());
</cfscript>` Yields: `moo moo`

Comment: @ScottStroz: "moo moo". Chuckle. Glad it worked. Sorry about not being able to test it properly before suggesting it. Trying to get CF10 installed on my work PC...